# Neutral synonym for "leaderboard"

Tags: synonyms

Is there a synonym for "leaderboard" that implies less of a value judgement of the criteria by which the items on the board are ranked?

I need to describe a dynamic table of **ordered** data (with the highest value at the top) about a sensitive and controversial topic without appearing to suggest approval or disapproval. I also want to avoid a using term that could be construed as flippant or ironic.

Comment: Why not just sort the table on some less controversial field - such as **name**?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use a term that does not imply any ranking, I would suggest simply *table* or *list* may be appropriate.

Given that the data is to be presented in an ordered fashion in the table you describe, I don't think there is any sure way to prevent a reader making a judgement about this ranking, be it positive or negative, if that is their inclination. The best you can do - short of an explicit disclaimer - is to present the data as baldly as possible using neutral language in the table itself, its accompanying caption, and when referring to the table elsewhere in the document.

Comment: To clarify, the entries in the table are ordered by a numerical value, highest to lowest, just like a leaderboard. I want to avoid implying that this value represents a positive or negative quality.

Answer (score 0):

If depends on the headings a bit but you can just refer to it as a table or figure.